# Separating the old data from a new one after parsing the data into a local buffer from a ring buffer

Tags: arrays, c, embedded

So I have a ring buffer that's used inside the USART's ISR to stores the user input and upon receiving `\r`, it calls the application callback where I parse the elements into a local buffer between the head and tail indices, but I see the following issues:

- the old data in the local buffer stays. So in case, the incoming data is shorter than the previous data, you'll see something like `'n','e','w','o','l','d'`.

Determining the length of the new data would help cause then I could just take the substring of it but determining the length by subtracting the head index from the tail won't work in case there was a wraparound.

E.g:

```
Ring buffer size: 9
Head index: 7
Tail index: 1
```

you get 3 more new chars and the head index becomes 1. So computing the length by mere subtraction won't work.

**tl;dr** - the issue i'm trying to get around is being able to separate the new data from the old data in a local buffer (which contains the parsed data between the head and tail index). The same issue will occur if the user inputs more data than the length of the ring buffer i.e it would override the old data. But with index, even you have a large enough buffer, you'd still see the same issue eventually.

Comment: First of all, I wonder why you use a ringbuffer, because you call the appl-cbk on `\r`, and actually, you should also do this, when the buffer is full. Then you could just use a normal array, and reset the index after the callback to 0. For a ringbuffer, it would require a read and a write index, both should never overtake each over (rd overtake wr means reading more then written, wr overtake rd meaning new data overwrites old data). Maybe its just easier to use a fill level. `write(b) { buf[wr]=in; wr = (wr+1)%size; fill++; }  read() { ret = buf[rd]; rd = (rd+1)%size; fill--; return ret;}`.

Comment: Doesn't the head index separate the old data from the new?  After you receive new data, the head pointer is pointing at the byte that separates new from old data.  Why would you read past the head pointer and into old data?